# Symfony routing problem

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I get this error regardless of what page I want to load:

```
404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception  
Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/contact" (/).
- error appears on any other page instead of /contact -even the homepage (/)
```

There aren't problems in routing, because the web site is running online (www.resursecrestine.ro)
It's not about running the website on some shared hosting, is about running the website on my Linux powered computer.

Can anybody please help?

Symfony log here: http://pastie.org/2344398
factories.yml here: http://pastie.org/2344677
routing.yml here http://pastie.org/2344685

Comment: Please provide the symfony logs.

Comment: Here are the logs: http://pastie.org/2344398

Comment: Is in your actions.class.php the function executeIndex(...) ?

Comment: Yes, the website is functional and works here: www.resursecrestine.ro. We set it 2 years ago and made the development from Windows. But I want to work from Linux now and I tried to set up the project on my Linux machine and I get this error. Is it from some configuration? What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Could you also paste the contents of your routing.yml and maybe the factories.yml (if it contains some routing rules). And have you triple checked that your configuration is correct (checked for the right application and environment).

Comment: I added them in the question body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not about the routing system, this is more a Symfony / Apache settings issue. I fixed it by properly installing the project from the Apache perspective, **carefully** following the Symfony tutorial:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

wrong order?

homepage section To the bottom

"/contact" match route "/"

```
terms_conditions:
  url:      /termeni-si-conditii
  param:    { module: home, action: termsConditions }
  class:    sfRequestHostRoute
  options:  { generate_shortest_url: true }
  requirements:
    sf_host: <?php echoln(sfConfig::get('app_text_url')); ?>

…

# added
contact:
  url:   /contact
  param: { module: {module-name}, action: {action-name} }
  class:    sfRequestHostRoute
  requirements:
    sf_host: <?php echoln(sfConfig::get('app_text_url')); ?>

homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: home, action: index }
  class:    sfRequestHostRoute
  requirements:
    sf_host: <?php echoln(sfConfig::get('app_text_url')); ?>
```

Comment: It's not about the order since the same routing.yml is working on www.resursecrestine.ro - it's probably something small that's keeping me from running the website :(